# Visual Studio 2019 stopped debugging, showing No symbols loaded and 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I've been debugging a C# single project solution with VS 2019 since it was installed more than a year ago.  It's set up for external host and uses the local web address in the project URL box.   To start debugging, I was able to just click the "> Web Server (Google Chrome) Button in the toolbar to start debugging the web site.

All of a sudden I was no longer able to click the button to debug. It gave the error, "Unable to start debugging on the web server.  The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden".  Again, local server (servername.domain.net/CS).  No changes to anything that I know of.

However, I could attach to w3wp.exe and debug that way.  That lasted about a day.  Then all my breakpoints would turn black when attaching and said, "The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for this document".

Started and stopped IIS and killed w3wp.exe many times.  Cleaned, rebuilt, and republished multiple times.  Deleted all the bin directories and NuGet project directories.  Tried looking in logs, inetpub/logs, only see what pages hit, no errors (might be wrong log).  The .dll and .pdb are both in the bin directory.

Configuration is set at debug, any CPU.  DEBUG=true in web.config.  Debug->Windows->Modules shows one line: Name=Script Code, Status=Symbols Loaded.  Right-clicking it, selecting Symbol Load Information just shows "Symbols Loaded" and nothing else.

I uninstalled/Reinstalled and none of the problems changed... same as they were before the uninstall.  So, I'm out of ideas.  What else can I try?

EDIT: BIG CLUE!
I'm sure this is a clue but I don't know what it means...
I have another web site (production) on this server.  I changed the Properties -> Web, Project URL to the other web, clicked the start button in the toolbar and it started debugging it!  Same code, just different target.  Looking at the Debug -> Windows -> Modules, there is a ton of them there now.

So, why would just changing the Project URL allow debugging?... How can I make it debug the original site (development)?  Hopefully, this makes sense to someone.

EDIT 2:
Confirming both webs are on the same server as Visual Studio and both using https, not http;

Comment: You may be using a certificate which has expired.

Comment: Good thought and I actually updated the SSL cert on 4/17.  Server has been restarted a number of times since.  I switched the web site to a self-signed cert and then back to the real one just to see if it would make a difference... It didn't\

Comment: The default version of TLS is the same as your browser settings.  So if the browser settings changed the version of TLS may also have changed.  Last June Microsoft did a security push which disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on server and not clients.  So client may be using 1.0 and 1.1 and server refusing.  But I do not thing so due to the 403 error.  More likely the server setting were changed to require HTTPS and you are still using HTTP.

Comment: I'm specifying https in the Project URL.  But look at the new edit.  It's working with the second web site on this server.

Comment: So what! It just means the connection is completing to one server but not completing to the other.  The best thing is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare working and non working.  TLS occurs before the Request is sent.  So on sniffer see if TLS and the version of TLS on both working and non working.  TLS will not occur if you are using HTTP,  Then check if Request is sent and if the request is HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: So what??   it's the same server... same box, same code, same browser, only thing different is the location on the hard drive and the name of the web.  VS  and webs are are on same server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231973/discussion-between-velocedge-and-jdweng).